# JPA: Map invalid database values to enums

Tags: java, jpa, openjpa

In my datamodel a have many entities where attributes are mapped to enumerations like this:

```
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private MySpecialEnum enumValue;
```

MySpecialEnum defines some fixed values. The mapping works fine and if the database holds a NULL-value for a column I get NULL in the enumValue-attribute too.
The problem is, that my backend module (where I have no influence on) uses spaces in CHAR-columns to identify that no value is set. So I get an IllegalArgumentException instead of a NULL-value.

So my question is: Is there a JPA-Event where I can change the value read from the database before mapping to the enum-attribute?
For the write-access there is the @PrePersist where I can change Null-values to spaces. I know there is the @PostLoad-event, but this is handled after mapping.

Btw: I am using OpenJpa shipped within WebSphere Application Server.

Answer (score 0):

You could map the enum-type field as `@Transient` (it will not be persisted) and map another field directly as String, synchronizing them in `@PostLoad`:

```
@Transient
private MyEnum fieldProxy;

private String fieldDB;

@PostLoad
public void postLoad() {
    if (" ".equals(fieldDB))
         fieldProxy = null;
    else
         fieldProxy = MyEnum.valueOf(fieldDB);
}
```

Use `get/setFieldProxy()` in your Java code.

As for synchronizing the other way, I'd do it in a setter, not in a `@PreUpdate`, as changes to `@Transient` fields probably do not mark the entity as modified and the update operation might not be triggered (I'm not sure of this):

```
public void setFieldProxy(MyEnum value) {
    fieldProxy = value;
    if (fieldProxy == null)
       fieldDB = " ";
    else
       fieldDB = value.name();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. But I am looking for a more general solution. For the way you suggest I have to write this code for every single enum field but I have to implement it for all enum fields in my data model. Btw I like to keep my entities simple and stupid.

Answer (score 0):

OpenJPA offers `@Externalizer` and `@Factory` to handle "special" database values.

See this: http://ci.apache.org/projects/openjpa/2.0.x/manual/manual.html#ref_guide_pc_extern_values

You might end up with something like this: *not tested...*

```
@Factory("MyClass.mySpecialEnumFactory")
private MySpecialEnum special;

...

public static MySpecialEnum mySpecialEnumFactory(String external) {
   if(StringUtils.isBlank(external) return null; // or why not MySpecialEnum.NONE;
   return MySpecialEnum.valueOf(external);
}
```